# node-webkit app is creating new nw folder in temp folder and not deleting the old one whenever app is upgrade or system is restarted

Tags: node.js, html, node-webkit

Every time, whenever the node webkit app is upgraded, the new `nw` folder (example: `nw8956_10711`) is created but the old `nw` folder is not deleted. It happens whenever system is restarted. It's causing lots of memory loss and forcing us to clean the temp folder after couples of days.
But whenever we quit the app `nw` folder gets deleted.

Is there a way to keep only one `nw` folder in the temp file?

Answer (score 0):

Consider calling a batch file to clean up like this...

```
rem For Windows7+
rd /s /q "\\?\C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp"

rem For Windows XP
rd /s /q "\\?\%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Temp"
```

From your app when the user exits with something like:

```
require('child_process').spawn('Cleanup.bat'),[]);
```

Comment: unable to run batch file !!